# Unable to route back from the Manage area in ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

1. I have a default normal unnamed area for the regular customers and the related controllers: Conrollers. There are no any area-related attributes on my contrellers in the Controllers forlder.
2. Also I have area "Manage" which contains the user management related controllers in the Area\Manage\Controllers folder.
3. My controllers in the Manage area have attributes: [Area("Manage")] (I think that falls under: "Conventional and attribute based routing cannot be mixed. In these cases the latter wins", but not sure how to fix this).
4. Here is an excerpt from the Startup.cs:

```
           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "categoryFilter",
                    pattern: "product/{action}/{category?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" });

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

5. What do I need to change in order to fix my issue
   I am able to browse through the site normally until I get to the views which are related to the controllers which are tagged with "Manage" and placed into the Manage area. Once I hit those views all other standard views receive the "/Manage/" path and I can't get back to them:
   originally Home was: https://localhost:12345/ and Contact was https://localhost:12345/Contact
   but then it becomes: https://localhost:44311/Manage and https://localhost:12345/Manage/Contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Url.RouteUrl() or Url.Action() and you didn't specify the area property in route data,
it stays on latest area, 
For example (when on manage/Test) :

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home"); //returns /Manage
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" }); //returns /
```